# Spark function for loading parquet file on memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, rdd

I have rdd loaded from Parquet file using SparkSQL

`data_rdd = sqlContext.read.parquet(filename).rdd`

I have noticed that actual reading from file operation gets executed once there is some aggregation function triggering spark job.

I need to measure computation time of the job without time it takes to read data from file. (i.e. same as input rdd(dataframe) is already there because it was created from sparkSQL)

Is there any function that triggers loading of file on executors memory?

I have tried `.cache()` but seems like it's still triggering reading operation as part of its job.

Comment: Spark will not read the file until any Action is performed on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark is lazy and will only do the computations it needs. 
You can `.cache()` it then `.count()` all the lines:

```py
data_rdd = sqlContext.read.parquet(filename).rdd
data_rdd.cache()
data_rdd.count()
```

Any set of computations that follow will start from the cached state of  `data_rdd` since we read the whole table using `count()`.

Comment: so you are saying if I do `data_rdd = sqlContext.read.parquet(filename).rdd.cache()` and do `count = data_rdd.count()` then any operation that uses data_rdd after that will not read data from files??

Comment: `count()` forces spark to do all the pending computations. The object can then be considered as loaded and all the compuations you do afterwards will use the cached state.